# Mongoose error on creating Model (using Step)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When trying to create a model in Mongoose I get the following error

[TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined]

I have no idea what's causing it

```
"use strict";
var Step = require('step');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

function randomFunction() {
    var categorySchema = new Schema({
        id: Number,
        name: String,
        description: String
    }, { collection: 'categories' });

    var Category;

    //...

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/grouping');

    new Step(
        function() { //Connect to mongodb
            var db = mongoose.connection;
            db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
            db.on('open', this);
        },
        function() {  //Create model
            console.log(categorySchema); //Logs the schema object right
            Category = mongoose.Model('Category', categorySchema);


        },
        function(err) {
            console.log(err);  //Error here
        });
    //...
}
```

I'm very new to Mongo (and fairly new to node) but I have absolutely no idea what the error message means.

I know I have options defined in the schema but I cant see how it would be undefined, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Note - this is a big cut out of the original code, this is the general structure (there's actually some code below `mongoose.Model('Cat...` but it gets skipped, I assume because the error is thrown by the `mongoose.Model` call as not even a `console.log("Hello");` is printed straight after it.

**EDIT** 
I've found that inside Mongoose (mongoose/lib/document.js) tries to get `this.schema` but it's undefined

```
function Document (obj, fields, skipId) { //Line 37
    this.$__ = new InternalCache;
    this.isNew = true;
    this.errors = undefined;

    var schema = this.schema; //-> undefined
    // ...
```

Comment: Are you sure, you are connected to MongoDB, the right code for connecting is `mongoose.connect('mongodb://host/database', function(err) { console.log('error occured', err); });` ?

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. I found that other connection code somewhere which worked better for me because it was seperated

Comment: Turns out I missed a line from my question, I'll add it in

Comment: In that case would you mind putting full dump of the error ?

Comment: Sure http://pastebin.com/uVSEanPH

Comment: Turns out I'm an idiot, my schema properties are defined with things like `name: String` instead of `name: 'string'` guessing that's the issue EDIT: nevermind, not the issue, apparently they can be either

Answer (score 88, accepted):

So it turns out I'm not the observent kind,

`mongoose.Model` should be `mongoose.model`

Comment: I, too, appear to be unobservant.

Comment: I, five, appear to be unobservant.

Comment: I, six, appear to be unobservant.

Comment: I, seven, appear to be unobservant

Comment: I, eleven, appear to be unobservant.

Comment: I, nine, appear to be unobservant.

Comment: I, twelve. maybe if their API wasn't so inconsistent: mongoose.Schema vs mongoose.model...

Comment: @kdazzle It is not inconsistent. `mongoose.Schema` is a class which can be instanciated, like this: `new mongoose.Schema()` – while `mongoose.model` is a function to compile a model, like this: `mongoose.model('name', schema)`

Comment: I, thirteen, appear to be unobservant.

Comment: I, fourteen, appear to be unobservant.

Comment: I, fifteen, appear to be unobservant.

Comment: I,sixteen, appear to be unobservant

Comment: I, seventeen, appear to be unobservant.

Comment: @kdazzle: thanks for the explanation, I get it now and would have stayed ignorant without it.

Comment: I, eighteen, appear to be unobservant.

Comment: I, nineteen, appear to be unobservant.

Comment: I, twenty, appear to be unobservant.

Comment: I, twenty one, appear to be unobservant.

Comment: I, 22nd, appear to be unobservant. Shame on me.

Comment: I, 23rd, appear to be unobservant.

Answer (score 3):

You can also get the same error for calling this.

`MyModel = new mongoose.model('<your model name>', mySchema)`

if you do remove the new.

Answer (score 1):

This error message will also be displayed when using model methods in a Promise chain such as:

```
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)

ScrapProducts()
  .then(mapToModel)
  .then(Product.create)
```

To solve it you must ensure that your mongoose model preserves its original context.

```
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)

ScrapProducts()
  .then(mapToModel)
  .then(function(data) {
    return Product.create(data)
  })
```

or better:

```
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)

ScrapProducts()
  .then(mapToModel)
  .then(Product.create.bind(Product))
```